# SPARQL: filter on both string and integer?

Tags: sparql

I'm testing SPARQL with Protégé on this data file
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/master/example/sparql-generate/result/gcloud_vm.ttl

Validated the following works:

```
PREFIX cocoon: <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/master/ontology_dev/cocoon.ttl>

SELECT ?VM ?cores
WHERE {
    ?VM a cocoon:VM ;
        cocoon:numberOfCores ?cores .

}
```

For example, it returns something like:

```
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-ULTRAMEM-80-PREEMPTIBLE  "80"@   
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-HIGHCPU-64-PREEMPTIBLE   "64"@   
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-STANDARD-2   "2"@    
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-F1-MICRO    "shared"@   
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-HIGHCPU-8-PREEMPTIBLE    "8"@    
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-HIGHCPU-32   "32"@   
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-HIGHMEM-16-PREEMPTIBLE   "16"@   
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-STANDARD-96-PREEMPTIBLE  "96"@   
https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/gcloud/CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-STANDARD-4   "4"@
```

I'm not sure if I can apply a filter on `?cores`, I tried the following, but they returned nothing:

```
cocoon:numberOfCores "shared" .
```

Or

```
FILTER(?cores = "4") .
```

I'd also like to apply filter on `?cores` (i.e. `> 4` and `< 8`), so I have to make it an `xsd:integer`? But then I have to get rid of `shared` which is about `< 1 core`

Comment: *All* values of `cocoon:numberOfCores` are strings (`rdf:langStrings`). Make them integers in your ttl. Unfortunately, it seems that the SPARQL plugin doesn't support type conversion via `xsd:integer()` or `xsd:int()`.

Comment: for some reason, Protege still depends on the Sesame library for the SPARQL support. unfortunately, the explicit cast functions have been introduced only in RDF4J (the successor of Sesame), see [this ticket](https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/pull/654). thus, somebody should maybe request an update to RDF4J in Protege - might be some larger change indeed, but I think it's worth given that it's still used Sesame 2.7 from something around year 2015

Comment: I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/protegeproject/rdf-library/issues/6), not sure if anybody of the developers will be interested in it and even has time to fix it before the next release which should be Protege 5.5 according to the latest pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw), impressive knowledge about Protégé.

In the end, I changed my data type to `xsd:decimal`. Seems to be enough for now.